# Object projection in geographic coordinate system

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, geospatial

I am trying to figure out how to *roughly* project the geographic position of an annotated object in an image?

**The Setup**

- A picture with a known object in it. i.e. we know the width/height.
- A bounding box highlighting where that object is in frame. X,Y,Width,Height.
- The *precise* longitude and latitude of the camera that took the picture. The Origin.
- The heading of the camera.
- The focal length of the camera.
- The camera sensor size.
- The height of the camera off the ground.

Can anyone point me toward a solution for *roughly* projecting the objects location from the image origin location, given those data points?

Comment: From the camera details you can get its angle of view (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view) in horizontal and vertical dimensions. From there isn't it a straightforward problem of ratios to calculate the distance the object is away from the camera? Is the `heading` spherical or is the camera horizontal? Are you trying to find the object's z coordinate also or just lat/long?

Comment: Thanks! The distance to the object I have somewhat figured out. But the problem more lies in how to calculate the delta to the left or right of origin. The object could be 50 meters away on the left. So projecting directly in front the distance away, would result in a pretty wide error. The camera is horizontal.

Comment: Project each of the corners of the bounding based on the angles (horizontal and vertical) that they represent in the image?  If you know their distance and their angles, and the origin can't you just calculate where they will be?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple if you assume an ellipsoidal surface for the Earth. If you need to use a Digital Terrain Model (DTM) things will get quickly more complicated. For example, your object may be visible in the image but occluded on the DTM because of various sources of error. In the following I assume you work with the ellipsoid.

Briefly, what you need to do is backproject the vertices of the image bounding box, obtaining four vectors (rays) in camera coordinates. You then transform them into Earth-Centered Earth-Fixed (ECEF) coordinates and solve for the intersection of the rays with the WGS-72 (or WGS-84) ellipsoid  as explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20780/point-of-intersection-for-a-ray-and-earths-surface).

I recommend using the [nvector](https://nvector.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library to help with this kind of calculations. You didin't specify the language you work with, but there are ports of nvector to many common languages, including Python and Matlab.